# Difference in number of rows in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

How can I take a difference in the counts of the number of rows in two different tables?

```
SQL> select count(*) from dual44;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         3

SQL> select count(*) from dual;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> (select count(*) from dual44)
  2  minus
  3  (select count(*) from dual)
  4  ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         3

SQL>
```

I need `2` as the result. The two tables might not necessarily have the same scehma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

minus operator is used to removed all records of first result set that are also contained in second. Use - (dash) operator here.

```
select ((select count(*) from dual44) - (select count(*) from dual)) from dual
```

Comment: I get this below the dash sign: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: yes you're right, you have to embed this in a valid select query

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) - (select count(*) from dual)
from dual44
```

[MINUS](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Result-Set/MINUSreturnsallthoserecordsfromthefirstquerybutnotthesecond.htm) is a SQL set operation that is not needed here, just use `-`.

Comment: I get this: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function (below the second count(*))

Comment: @Amoeba if you use `GROUP BY` clause  all individual column expressions listed in `SELECT` must be under `GROUP BY` or aggregated like MIN,MAX etc.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT (a.count-b.count)
 FROM
   (SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM dual44) a,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM dual) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following is really fast** ( less than 1 second for tables of hundreds of millions records) provided that your statistics are up to date *(which is highly recommended).*

```
select 
(
(select u.NUM_ROWS from user_tables u where u.TABLE_NAME='JOBS')
 - 
(select u.NUM_ROWS from user_tables u where u.TABLE_NAME='COUNTRIES')
 ) DIFF
from dual


     DIFF
----------
        -6
```

Sample code applies to HR schema of ORACLE. You can change the table names.

***The two tables might not necessarily have the same schema.***

Edit on Jeffrey Kemp's comment:

If tables are on different schemas, you have to use `dba_tables`, if you have the privileges.

Just add the schema name to the table name. i.e. `HR.JOBS`

Comment: (1) if they're not in the same schema you won't find the stats in `user_tables`; (2) The OP never specified they only want a rough estimate based on statistics, nor did they mention performance was an issue.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp (1) Thanks, you are right, I've updated the answer. (2) I think performance is something that one should often,if not always, take into account. Yes, OP didn't specify but especially in OLAP databases, where tables are not frequently updated, this seems a feasible way to me.

Answer (score -1):

In **Sqlite**, this would works:

```
Select (Select count(col1) from Table1) - (Select count(col2) from Table2))
```