# Minus operation gives wrong answer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the result of the minus operation of join tables which means that I am finding unmatched records.

I tried:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mp_v1 mp
left join cm_v1 sop
on mp.study_name=sop.study_name and
sop.site_id=sop.site_id
--where mp.study_name='1101'
MINUS
SELECT count(*) FROM iv_mpv1 mp
inner join cm sop
on mp.study_name=sop.study_name and
sop.site_id=sop.site_id
--where mp.study_name='1101'
```

output: the count of this gives me 171183251

but when I run the first query individually I get 171183251 for left outer join and 171070345 for inner join so the output needs to be 112906. I am not sure where my query is wrong. Could anyone please give your opinion.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Comment: `MINUS` doesn't subtract, it compares rows. `171183251` is not returned by the 2nd query, so it is returned by `MINUS`. [The Oracle MINUS operator is used to return all rows in the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/minus.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference in number of rows in two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710919/difference-in-number-of-rows-in-two-tables)

Comment: The second answer (chose because of readability purpose) in the link provide by @Andrew is something you can do with your requirement.

Comment: @Andrew that was one of the link I saw a min before you posted and anyway thanks it works.

Comment: [SQL set operators refresher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html#GUID-5CB549AF-5A4F-453E-B164-49CAC8F94CBF).

Answer (score 1):

If you want unmatched records you wouldn't use `MINUS` on the counts.  The query would look more like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ((SELECT *
       FROM mp_v1 mp LEFT JOIN
            cm_v1 sop
            USING (study_name, site_id)
      ) MINUS
      (SELECT *
       FROM iv_mpv1 mp LEFT JOIN
            iv_cmv1 sop
            USING (study_name, site_id)
      )
     ) x;
```

Also note that `MINUS` removes duplicates, so if you have duplicates within each set of tables, then they only count as one row.

The `SELECT *` assumes that the tables have the same columns and compatible types -- which makes sense given the gist of the question.  You may need to list the particular columns you care about.

Comment: `x` is just the alias of the subquery.

Comment: "x" is alias for the subquery. "I get error" is useless. What error? Query *looks* OK, but will fail if result of those SELECT statements results in different column set (because tables are different). Rewrite them to contain only columns you're interested in.